# How to Reuse Rspec Tests for Load Testing

Tags: rspec, jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing

I have Rspec tests that I use for testing Restful endpoints but they run only once. What I need to do is to run them in random order, multiple times and using different threads. I was looking into JMeter but I could not find a way to run Rspec tests in JMeter. Is this possible or should I use another framework to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Rspec is tool for writing tests that are testing if your code yields correct results. What you need for load testing is tool like JMeter, ab or siege.

Comment: Yes, Jmeter has perfect support for what I am looking for, but I need to write the same tests again. I was just wondering if there is a way to trigger the Rspec tests that I already have.